# selenide has a problem with chrome versions newer than 114

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenide

When i try to open any site using selenide with chrome version newer than 114 i get an error:

```
HTTP 404 executing https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_119 2023-12-02T15:58:16.710+04:00 WARN 47209 --- [ scheduling-1] i.g.b.wdm.versions.VersionDetector : Exception reading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_119 to get latest version of chromedriver (Error HTTP 404 executing https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_119)
```

This problem is solved in selenium 4.6.x but even the newest version of selenide 7.0.3 uses selenium 4.15 which still has this problem.
this is due to google changes:

> Current Releases
> If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard. This page provides convenient JSON endpoints for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.

This is how I solved the problem...
**part of pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**My config bean for create instance of WebDriver:**

```
@Component
public class DriverConfig {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (Objects.isNull(driver)) {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            options.setHeadless(true);
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

**Setup this webDriver:**

```
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driverConfig.getDriver());
```

it doesn't seem like the right decision to me.
I would be glad if someone could suggest a better solution to the problem.
and I hope that selenide authors will release a fix for such cases.
thank you all in advance for your answers!